# Does the following Append HTML with the Text from each instance of a Class to that instance of the Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, jquery-append

I'm trying to get the following code to grab the text from each instance of .banners_text_line and precede it with a span.shadow, enclosing a copy of the text from the class. Here is what I'm thinking for the jquery:

```
<script>

$('.banners_text_line').each(function(){
$(this).append('<span class="shadow">'$(this).text()'</span>');
});

</script>
```

If there were two instances of .banners_text_line  with the first having the text, "hello world," and the next saying, "how are you," then I'm trying to get the output to display:

```
<div class=".banners_text_line"><span class="shadow">hello world</span>hello world</div>
...
<div class=".banners_text_line"><span class="shadow">how are you</span>how are you</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out the concatenation operator:

```
$(this).append('<span class="shadow">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
```

Of course, you'll get better performance and won't have to worry about concatenation if you do it this way:

```
var t = $(this);
t.append($(document.createElement('span')).addClass('shadow').text(t.text()));
```

Comment: After concatenating, I'm still not getting a span to appear. Would it matter if the div had another class? Some of the divs have multiple classes:

    <div class="banners_text_line league">...</div>

Comment: @beta208, as long as it has the class you're selecting for, it doesn't matter how many other classes it has.

Comment: @beta208, out of curiosity, you are running your script after the DOM has loaded, right?

Comment: Oh dang, that's my bad. I bet that was the issue. Thanks a bunch.